# Not able to connect to redis and redis cluster after removing stunnel

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, stunnel

I am not able to connect to redis and redis cluster after removing stunnel from my springboot application.
I am using properties file and config pool is fetched from Jedis.java file using this properties file.
Eariler there was stunnel.config using which the application what connecting to redis and everything was working fine. What changes do I need to make now after I have removed stunnel completely to enable my app to use the redis again.